# Creating session key without worrying about uniqueness

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a script on the frontend that sets a session value based on a given parameter when a button is clicked (via AJAX).

At first I thought that in order to set a unique session key, I can base it off the pathname + the parameter (Which is unique per page, so the combination pathname + parameter has to be unique).

Then in order to retrieve the session data from the same route I simply take the pathname and concat it with the parameter. For example:

the URL is: `www.example.com/path/name`, and the parameter is `some_unique_id_in_the_page`, then the session key would be `path_name_some_unique_id_in_the_page`.

And in the backend I would simply retrieve it by getting the pathname using Laravel's `path()` method on the request and concat the parameter.

This works when retrieving the session key from the same route, but when I need it from another route (when there is a link on that route for example), the `path()` is no longer the correct path so the session key doesn't match.

My other solutions are a bit more cumbersome:

1. To use a unique parameter for the entire site on each page, and make sure there aren't collisions
2. When I need to retrieve the data from another route, then also pass the URL from which I want that key (passing it as an query string or input), so if for example I need to retrieve `path_name_some_unique_id_in_the_page` from another URL such as `www.example.com/another/path`, I should pass it `www.example.com/path/name` in the request as well

Edit: I add some code:

In the URL `www.example.com/path/name`, there is a form that is submitted to the backend. In the backend it saves the data into session:

```
// sending ajax from `www.example.com/path/name`
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "PathNameAjax.php",
  data: { pathname: window.location.pathname.split('?')[0] }
})
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function PathNameAjaxSaveSession(Request $request)
{
    $pathname = $request->input('pathname');
    // $data = getting data
    // $key = generating the key using path and id which will be path_name_some_unique_id_in_the_page
    session([$key => $data]);
}
```

And then because I only used it so far in the PathName index page, I did not have to worry about getting the session key because it was in the `$request`:

```
public function PathNameIndex(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->path(); // from the request directly, not input or query string
    $unique_id = $request->input('some_unique_id_in_the_page');
    // $key = I can get the key by needing only a single parameter = the unique id in that page
    $data = session($key);
}
```

But now if I want it from another route, like `www.example.com/another/path`, I won't have that path:

```
public function AnotherPath(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->path(); // different pathname
    $unique_id = $request->input('some_unique_id_in_the_page');
    $data = session($key);
}
```

At first, I only needed to use that session key in the page itself, then I needed to get that data in other pages, that's why I used part of the pathname as a key to create uniqueness. But now when I need it in other pages I will also need to path a 3rd parameter every time. Unless I should do it differently

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You would generally create the session and store the session key in the user's cookies. That way you don't have to add it to the URL parameters. It's difficult to say what you are trying to achieve without some code. Why not use a normal user session? The path you are in is not relevant usually if you just use [Laravel's built in session management](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session).

Comment: I will add more code to clarify, I am using Laravel's session management but I still need keys for specific things

Comment: @PeterKrebs, Salketer, I added code. If that makes more sense - at first I needed to use that session key on on that same page so I didn't think about it too much. Then I had to use that session data on other routes

Comment: @Salketer I want to be able to pass some `id` in the frontend that might not be unique for the entire site, but then generate unique session key to be used in other requests, given only that `id`, but I think that's impossible, I will have to pass another parameter

Comment: You can just store the key in another session variable. Like `session([$key => $data, 'key' => $key]);` so the key is always in the same place and can be gotten from the session itself without any parameter from every request. Every unique key will generate a different dataset in that case but I assume that's what you want.

Comment: @PeterKrebs yes I want something like that. But I want the frontend developer to be able to set his own unique id in that page, and then in the back I can retrieve it using only that specific page's unique id. So if 2 pages are set with the same id (It is probably going to be some element's id in that page), it will not be possible to tell how to get the right one if I need the data of either of them in another page. (If two pages have `some_unique_id_in_the_page` as the id, and I need to get one of them in another page, how to know which one to get? Currently I must pass the URL as well)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function setSessionPathValue(path,value){
    $key = path; // Maybe sanitize or something?
    session([$key => $data]);
}

public function getSessionPathValue(path)
{
    $key = path; // Maybe sanitize or something?
    $data = session($key);
}
```

So when you want to save from the ajax call:

```
setSessionPathValue($request->input('pathname'));
```

When you want to get value from path itself:

```
getSessionPathValue($request->input('pathname'));
```

When you want to get value of a path from somewhere else:

```
getSessionPathValue($pathname);
```

So now, you just have to figure out $pathname when you are on another page.

Comment: Exactly which is what I do now. But that means that the frontend developer will need to pass that variable every time he wants to redirect to another path that uses this session which is annoying and I thought there might be a way to only pass a unique parameter from that page itself (Like an element id, which in this example is the `some_unique_id_in_the_page`. Now both needs to be passed: the URL, and the unique id

Comment: Actually, no. Only the URL, which is used as the unique id in this case.